# Clear all Cmake variables at once

Tags: c++, cmake

Is there any command that I can place in a CMakeLists.txt file to clear all the variables that have been defined?
If I understood well I can selectively clear them doing 'unset' selectively on each variable, but I would need to do something more like 'unset(*)'.

Comment: Something like that will be dangerous since "clear ***all***" includes system variables that should not be cleared. What is the problem you're trying to solve by "clear all variables"?

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question "clear all variables excluding system variables"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unset all variables like this:

```
get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
    unset(${_variableName})
endforeach()
```

This essentially gets all variables at the global scope and calls `unset` on them. As @'Some programmer dude' noted, this is not recommended, and will likely cause CMake to stop functioning correctly.